# App is not working on Android 4.0.3 but on Android 2.3.4 it is

Tags: android, version, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've an app that is working perfectly on Android 2.3.4 (Emulator/Phone). But I tried to install it on Android 4.0.3 (Emulator/Phone) and when i run it is not working. It shows me this message

```
"Unfortunately AppName has stopped"
```

When appears me an error the app is executing these classes:

```
public class EmpleadosAct extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> datos;
private ListView list;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActualizarVehiculos();

}

public void ActualizarVehiculos() {

    try {
        NotesCenter messageCenter = new NotesCenterImpl();

        List<Vehiculo> vehiculo = messageCenter.getVehiculo();

        for (Vehiculo v : vehiculo) {
            AndroidOpenDbHelper androidOpenDbHelperObj = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(
                    this);

            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelperObj
                    .getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(AndroidOpenDbHelper.matricula, v.matricula);

            long affectedColumnId = sqliteDatabase.insert("Vehiculos",
                    null, contentValues);
            sqliteDatabase.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.v("blah", ex.getMessage());

    }

}
}
```

The second class:

```
public class SeleccionarEmpleado extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listaEmpleados;
private EditText ECont;
String text;
Bundle dataBundle;
public EmpleadosAct actemple;
protected AppApplication app;

private ListAdapter uGraduateListAdapter;

private ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo> pojoArrayList;
private String contraseña;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seleccionarempleado);

    ***Intent actServicios = new Intent(this, EmpleadosAct.class);
    startActivity(actServicios);***

    listaEmpleados = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListaEmpleados);
    listaEmpleados.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<UndergraduateDetailsPojo>();

    uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());

    listaEmpleados.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.actualizar:
        //Intent actualizarEmpleados = new Intent(this,EmpleadosAct.class);
        //startActivity(actualizarEmpleados);


        //return true;

    case R.id.opciones:
        Toast.makeText(SeleccionarEmpleado.this, "Save is Selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent addNewUndergraduateIntent = new Intent(this,
            InsertarPedido.class);
    startActivity(addNewUndergraduateIntent);
}

public List<String> populateList() {

    List<String> uGraduateNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query("Empleados", null, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String idempleado = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.idempleado));
        String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.nombre));
        String primerapellido = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.primerapellido));
        String segundoapellido = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.segundoapellido));
        String contra = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.contra));

        UndergraduateDetailsPojo ugPojoClass = new UndergraduateDetailsPojo();
        ugPojoClass.setIdEmpleado(idempleado);
        ugPojoClass.setNombreEmpleado(nombre);
        ugPojoClass.setPrimerApellido(primerapellido);
        ugPojoClass.setSegundoApellido(segundoapellido);
        ugPojoClass.setContra(contra);

        pojoArrayList.add(ugPojoClass);

        uGraduateNamesList.add(nombre + " " + primerapellido + " "
                + segundoapellido);
    }

    sqliteDatabase.close();

    return uGraduateNamesList;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uGraduateListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    listaEmpleados.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    UndergraduateDetailsPojo clickedObject = pojoArrayList.get(arg2);

    String Empleado = clickedObject.getNombreEmpleado() + " "
            + clickedObject.getPrimerApellido() + " "
            + clickedObject.getSegundoApellido();

    Empleado empleadoseleccionado = new Empleado();
    empleadoseleccionado.id = clickedObject.getIdEmpleado();
    empleadoseleccionado.nombre = Empleado;
    app = (AppApplication)getApplicationContext();
    app.setempleadoActual(empleadoseleccionado);
    app.setempleadoId(empleadoseleccionado);

}
}
```

At first it is executing the second class, in the second class there is an Intent that opens the first class. First class adds data to android SQLite database from some remote server. And then the second class is showing this results from android SQLite database.

This is the Log:

```
06-04 21:08:13.034: W/dalvikvm(517): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception    (group=0x409c01f8)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  activity ComponentInfo{dokesim.net/myapp.net.EmpleadosAct}: java.lang.NullPointerException:  println needs a message
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.util.Log.v(Log.java:117)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at myapp.net.EmpleadosAct.ActualizarVehiculos(EmpleadosAct.java:133)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at    myapp.net.EmpleadosAct.onCreate(EmpleadosAct.java:24)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-04 21:08:13.054: E/AndroidRuntime(517):  ... 11 more
```

The Second Log:

```
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720): Error happened: 
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119 )
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at myapp.net.HttpNote.doGet(HttpNote.java:32)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at myapp.net.NotesCenterImpl.getVehiculo(NotesCenterImpl.java:23)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at myapp.net.EmpleadosAct.ActualizarVehiculo(EmpleadosAct.java:91)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at myapp.net.EmpleadosAct.onCreate(EmpleadosAct.java:24)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-04 21:40:03.225: V/blah(720):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So what is it causing that in 2.3.4 android is working everything fine and in 4.0.3 it isn't? There is some problem with my code that doesn't support 4.0.3 version?

Thanks for any answer or suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

```
Log.v("blah", ex.getMessage());
```

The problem is that `ex.getMessage()` is returning `null`. You could check for `null`, but a better way is to pass the exception explicitly as a third parameter to the log method:

```
Log.v("blah", "Error happened: ", ex);
```

Comment: Even better, pass the exception as the root cause: `Log.v(TAG, "Error while _________", ex);`

Comment: Thanks for your time. I modified my code and I added the second Log.